# Go Mod trying to download a non-existent package

Tags: go, go-modules

Go mod giving below error when I use command `go mod tidy`

```
go: finding module for package github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/Backend/MySqlDBLib/MySqlConnInit
github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/UserService/Handler imports
        github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/MySqlDBLib/Model imports
        github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/Backend/MySqlDBLib/MySqlConnInit: cannot find module providing package github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/Backend/MySqlDBLib/MySqlConnInit: module github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/Backend/MySqlDBLib/MySqlConnInit: gi
t ls-remote -q origin in /Users/nirmalvatsyayan/gocode/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/49cdef3e2697979b0da
938baa0f74bd154458398de9ef7d91f6a7c1ab8936bdd: exit status 128:
        remote: Repository not found.
        fatal: repository 'https://github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/Backend/
' not found
```

The problem is it is still trying to refer a path  `github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/Backend/MySqlDBLib/MySqlConnInit` which is non-existent now, it is `github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/MySqlDBLib/MySqlConnInit`. In line 3 it is pointing to the correct path `github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/MySqlDBLib/Model imports` but in line 4 it's pointing to older path again `github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/Backend/MySqlDBLib/MySqlConnInit`. Why is go mod pointing to a repo which no longer exists even when it's basically pointing to new repo first.

There is no reference of `github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/Backend/MySqlDBLib/MySqlConnInit` internally from `github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/MySqlDBLib/Model`, in code it does refer to correct directory which is `github.com/NirmalVatsyayan/MySqlDBLib/MySqlConnInit`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `replace` option in your `go.mod`

like :

```
replace (
    fake/path/of/package => ../real/address
)
```

then run `go build your_main_file.go` or `go run your_main_file.go`